# Loading KieBase into KieContainer

Tags: drools

I am creating KieBase dynamically and creating a local cache to cache. For each request i am looking into the cache to check the availability in order to not build the base again and improve performance. The KieBase can keep getting updated as the version of the rules gets updated. This will be handled as part of the cache stratergy.

I would like to know if there is a mechanism to load these Kiebase into a KieContainer for each request as i would like to dispose the Container once the request is complete.

Comment: So you want to add and remove a KieBase to an existing KieContainer dynamically?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i am trying to build an application that creates and executes dynamically. Based on this i would like to create the KieBase dynamically.

Comment: And the KieContainer already exists?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes I would create and dispose the containers dynamically based on a request.